# how to find 50% point after curve fitting using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting

I have used numpy in python to fit my data to a sigmoidal curve. How can I find the vaue for X at y=50% point in the curve after the data is fit to the curve

```
enter code here`import numpy as np
enter code here`import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
   y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
   return y

xdata = np.array([0.0,   1.0,  3.0, 4.3, 7.0,   8.0,   8.5, 10.0, 12.0])
ydata = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.43,  0.7, 0.89, 0.95, 0.99])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
print popt

x = np.linspace(-1, 15, 50)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='fit')
pylab.ylim(0, 1.05)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and the behavior you're expecting by providing example code.

Comment: For a complete sigmoidal curve it will be `0, f(x=0)`...

Comment: This finds  a curve
how do I find the 50% x value after data fitting
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def sigmoid(x, x0, k):
     y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0)))
     return y

xdata = np.array([0.0,   1.0,  3.0, 4.3, 7.0,   8.0,   8.5, 10.0, 12.0])
ydata = np.array([0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.11, 0.43,  0.7, 0.89, 0.95, 0.99])

popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata)
print popt

x = np.linspace(-1, 15, 50)
y = sigmoid(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='fit')
pylab.ylim(0, 1.05)
pylab.legend(loc='best')
pylab.show()

Comment: @user3395925 you can post your comment as an answer...

Comment: sorry I didnt get what you meant?

Comment: I edited my post and put the full comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to solve the function you found for `y(x) = 0.50`. You can use one of the [root finding tools of scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#root-finding), though these only solve for zero, so you need to give your function an offset:

```
def sigmoid(x, x0, k, y0=0):
   y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) + y0
   return y
```

Then it's just a matter of calling the root finding method of choice:

```
from scipy.optimize import brentq

a = np.min(xdata)
b = np.max(xdata)
x0, k = popt
y0 = -0.50

solution = brentq(sigmoid, a, b, args=(x0, k, y0))  # = 7.142
```

---

*In addition to your comment:*

My code above uses the original `popt` that was calculated with your code. If you do the curve fitting with the updated `sigmoid` function (with the offset), `popt` will also contain a fitted parameter for `y0`.

Probably you don't want this.. you'll want the curve fitted for `y0=0`. This can be done by supplying a guess for the `curve_fit` with only two values. This way the default value for `y0` of the sigmoid function will be used:

```
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoid, xdata, ydata, p0 = (1,1))
```

Alternatively, just declare two seperate sigmmoid functions, one with the offset and one without it.

Comment: @user3395925 I ran your script and the fit looks decent to me. Not perfect but still reasonable.. The data that you've given doesn't allow for a better fit I suppose.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your answer because it says too many arguments to unpack for popt