# Error trying to find/print the x-value when y = 0.5 on a curve fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to print out the x-value for y = 0.50 for a curve fit and I have tried to adapt to the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277982/how-to-find-50-point-after-curve-fitting-using-numpy) but I am getting the following error code of :-

*TypeError: brentq() got multiple values for keyword argument 'args'*

Aren't all the values within the sigmoidscaled() function supposed to be within args here? Or am I misinterpreting something?

```
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from matplotlib.pyplot import *
from scipy.optimize import brentq
import numpy as np

n = 20 #20 trials
ydata = [0/n, 9.0/n, 9.0/n, 14.0/n, 17.0/n] #Divided by n to fit to a plot of y =1
xdata = np.array([ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0])


#The scaled sigmoid function
def sigmoidscaled(x, x0, k, lapse, guess, y0=0):
    F = (1 + np.exp(-k*(x-x0))) 
    z = guess + (1-guess-lapse)/F + y0
    return z

p0=[1,1,0,0] 
popt, pcov = curve_fit(sigmoidscaled, xdata, ydata, p0, bounds=((-np.inf, -np.inf, 0.,0.), (np.inf, np.inf, 0.5, 0.5)))


#Start and End of x-axis, in spaces of n. The higher the n, the smoother the curve.
x = np.linspace(1,5,20)
#The sigmoid values along the y-axis, generated in relation to the x values and the 50% point.
y = sigmoidscaled(x, *popt)

pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='Psychometric Raw', color = 'blue')
pylab.plot(x,y, label='Psychometric Fit', color = 'blue')
#y axis range.
pylab.ylim(0, 1)
#Replace x-axis numbers as labels and y-axis numbers as percentage
xticks([1., 2., 3., 4., 5.], ['C1','CN2','N3','CN4','S5'])
yticks([0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0], ['0%','20%','40%','60%','80%','100%'])
pylab.legend(loc='best')
xlabel('Conditions')
ylabel('% perceived more sin like')
pylab.show() 

a = np.min(xdata)
b = np.max(xdata)
x0, k, guess, lapse = popt
y0 = 0.50

solution = brentq(sigmoidscaled, a, b, p0, args=(x0, k, guess, lapse, y0))
```

Comment: we need the full traceback,  and probably the signature of the brentq function as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is `p0` when calling `brentq`

```
solution = brentq(sigmoidscaled, a, b, p0, args=(x0, k, guess, lapse, y0))
```

If you look at the [parameters for `brentq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.brentq.html), you can see that there is no parameter accepting a list after your `a` and `b` interval parameters. Hence, the `args` parameter becomes unexpected to the function's signature with the additional sequence. I don't see how `p0` is required for `brentq`  in any case, although I'm not an experienced with it, I would think it would just be required when curve fitting.